# why setting input.value equal to empty string doesn't remove recently pressed key?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, input

In below code if I press 'a' after some keys  it should remove everything from input including but 'a' is not going away in below code.

```
const input = document.querySelector("input");   

function type(e) {
  if (e.key === "a") {
    console.log("helo");
    input.value = "";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", type);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is that the `keydown` event fires before the character is added to the input. To resolve this, you must use the `keyup` event.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("exampleInput");

function type(e) {
  if (e.key === "a") {
    console.log("helo");
    input.value = "";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", type);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="exampleInput" />
```

Comment: I can't see any `keydown` used in the question!!! It is basically the same code between the question and answer!

Comment: Do no edit code in question! Making it a live snippet may be a good thing, but changing it entirely is definitely not.

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, that edit was unintentional. You'll see I already submitted a correction prior to you editing it yourself.

Comment: Alright, be more cautious the first time next time. Also, listening to keyup might not be the best. E.g we can fool your script by pressing Shift key after pressing "a" and before releasing it. Indeed, in this case, while the keydown and input events were "a", the keyup is now "A".

Comment: @Kaiido That is correct. Ideally, you would listen for the change event, check the last character for the input value, then see if that value is equal to "a". If so, clear the input and write to the console, as the OP intends.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck input event is more suited than change

Comment: @Kaiido Do you mind providing an explanation as to why you believe that?

Comment: because "change" will fire only when the input looses focus whereas "input" will fire as soon as the character would have been input.

Answer (score 0):

The handler fires *before* the default action of the `keydown` fires. This is why you can use `event.preventDefault()` on key events - the handlers fire *before* the default action occurs, which is why the default actions are cancelable with `preventDefault()`.

So, for what you're trying to do, clear the value *and* call `preventDefault()`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

window.addEventListener("keydown", type);

function type(e) {
  if (e.key === "a") {
    console.log("clearing");
    input.value = "";
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input>
```